# How to show Selected linkbutton amongs set of linkbuttons in asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, css

i have one aspx page on which. set of linkbuttons on it.

```
linkbutton1

linkbutton2

linkbutton3

linkbutton4

linkbutton5
```

if i click on any of them. it should be highlighted.

These linkbuttons are in the table.

thanks for any help.

Comment: what table does `the table` refer to? what does it mean for a linkbutton to be *selected* ? clicked? what does it mean for them to be *highlighted* ? some css effect? do you want the postback event to happen or not? if not, why are they linkbuttons?

Comment: i mentioned selected means. clicked on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't precisely say what is the structure of the table therefore any javascript/DOM parsing we might post here might be invalid. Also, do you want this effect to be entirely client-side, or do you want a asp solution with postback? Also, I don't get your comment above, can you please tell again what "highlighted" means to you?

Comment: sorry all of that. inconvenience . that set of link button are as what i placed above. if i selected means click any one of them. it means it is highlighted. means differ from rest of linkbuttons. ok. any code is accepted . whether its code behind or javascript or css class. doesn't matter. ok. thanks. for your comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add a CssClass to any of your linkbuttons, something like

`<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="linkbtn" />`

You can define the highlighted style in CSS like

```
.linkbtn .highlighted { color: red; }
```

and use some javascript to toggle classes. In jQuery it would look like:

```
$(".linkbtn").click(function () {
   $(".linkbtn").removeClass("highlighted");
   $(this).addClass("highlighted");
});
```

---

in ASP.Net just use

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton4" OnClick="LinkButton4_Click" runat="server"/>
```

and in codebehind

```
private void SetHighlighted(LinkButton btn)
{
  LinkButton1.CssClass = "";
  LinkButton2.CssClass = "";
  LinkButton3.CssClass = "";
  LinkButton4.CssClass = "";
  LinkButton5.CssClass = "";

  btn.CssClass = "highlighted";
}

protected void LinkButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SetHighlighted((LinkButton)sender);
}
```

do this for every linkbutton

Comment: be sure that each linkbutton points to LinkButton4_Click as it's OnClick event handler. just for clarification...

Comment: hey!!! for css style sheet i am doing this much of coding? 

Is it good thing as per the programing point of view?

Comment: thank you very much.. for these much of work. but it is very much longer than i should expect. sorry buddy

Comment: Downvote reason?! The solution does exactly what Sikender asks.

Comment: I agree, you can set the styles of the links when clicked, so i dont think this deserves a downvote...

Comment: hope the thread starter wouldn't mind, would you care to show us what you have done so far as to help you specifically on what you want achieved and how you want it written?

Comment: +1 Not only because this is the correct answer which takes multiple views into account, but also because whoever down voted it was obviously an idiot. It's a bit strange how everyone got a down vote and every single comment by Sikender got an up vote... weird. But nice work Jan, perfectly done with absolute minimal information.

Comment: it's working. if i add .js file. its a good code. and exactly . what i  am saying. but if i have more than 5 buttons means. 10 and above buttons, so much coding is needed. anyway. i did it as my own ways. thanks. thank you. so much.

Answer (score 4):

you can easily take care of this with css.

when you handle the linkbutton click event set the CSSClass property of the linkbutton to a class which differentiates it from the other linkbuttons in the list.

for instance, on page load you can have all linkbuttons CSSClass property set to Link and have this class defined to be your standard look and feel for hyperlinks. 8pt, tahoma, underlined etc.

create another class called LinkSelected and have it be 8pt, tahoma, underlined, and bold.

in your linkbutton click handler set `myLink.CSSClass="LinkSelected";` or `((LinkButton)sender).CSSClass="LinkSelected";`

you can define Link and LinkSelected class either inline (not recommended) or in a separate .css file.

give it a try and let me know if you need more details.

Comment: jans answer is exactly what i would add for detail.

Comment: Try to refresh your cache browser.

Answer (score 0):

I build the same in my pages the last weeks often.

As I see you have 2 options, regarding your code behind, that I don't know:

1) Your link button are linked to a special site (as hyperlinks). Than you can found out by the actual site which is clicked an hover it.

2) Your linkbutton only acitvate code, than you can make a normal "linkbutton1.Font.Bold = true" or something like this.

If you want it by CSS as my knowlegde it is not possible, because there are not rendered as a -tag.

Comment: i can do that in .net using some code. which is very perfect if you want to see it. i will tell you. give me comment. i will put it here. for you. but your answer is absolutely down track